# Why is Firefox Using 2 Gigabytes of RAM?

Tags: firefox, memory, performance, lag

I have version 26.0. Firefox uses 2 gigabytes of RAM minimum with only one tab open. I've tried uninstalling add-ons, disabling plug-ins, everything, but nothing helps. What do I do?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the profile itself? This a new problem?

Comment: Only on my new laptop, never had it before. How do I delete the profile?

Comment: The Mozilla website has the information you seek

Comment: I don't know what that did, but it did it.

Comment: Please define "everything". Did you try using [Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) already?

Comment: open **about:memory** and export this int a textfile, upload it to pastebin and post a link-

Comment: Personally I would upgrade to FF 27 and see what that does for you

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments to the question and as suggested by [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound), [**deleting the Firefox user profile**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) solved the problem for the OP.